# Incompatiability of bigoplus and qedhere

Tags: incompatibility

When I use `\[\bigoplus\limits blah blah, \qedhere\]`, I find `\bigoplus` becomes bigger and bold. I don't know how to make it normal. Please hep me out, thanks.

Comment: Please give us a compilable MWE. When I add the minimum in order to compile, I do not see any difference with or without the `\qedhere` command.

Comment: I use  proof  style in theorem environment and I want to put the qedsymbol in the last line.

Comment: Well, show us an MWE which we can compile. You say that your symbol "becomnes bigger and bold". As this is not reproducible for the snippet you gave us, we can not help.

Comment: That's the normal behavior of `\bigoplus` in a displayed equation and has nothing to do with `\qedhere`.

Comment: Along the line of egreg's observation, you could employ `{\textstyle\bigoplus\limits_{blah}^{blah}}` to keep it in textstyle, even inside of a displayed equation.

Comment: @egreg: But how I can I make \bigoplus normal in a displayed equation, because I only know this method to put the qedsymbol at the end of that long formula?

Comment: @ksj03 That's the normal `\bigoplus`.

Comment: A further question: what if I have already used another style, e.g. scriptstyle?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I note that you've asked a number of questions on this site, but have still not "accepted" any answers to your questions.  The way to acknowledge a helpful answer to your questions is to click the up-arrow to the left of the given answer.  If a question of yours has multiple answers, you can "upvote" more than one.  However, if there is one answer that is best, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark to the left of the question.  This tells the readers which answer was best for your question.  It also provides a measure of "reputation score" to those who took the time to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I really didn't realize that. Since you have taken the trouble to teach me how to do it, I will do this from now on. Thanks very much..

Comment: There are no apologies necessary.  It's all part of learning how to use the site effectively.  Sometimes, we all need hints on how things are supposed to be done.  Again, glad to have you participating at the site.  And there is nothing to stop you from revisiting your older questions, and voting/accepting answers.  If you click on your name icon at the top of the page, you will go to a summarized page of your prior activities.  You can also upvote any question or answer (of others) that you find edifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acknowledging egreg's observation that the issue is not with `\qedhere`, but rather the use of `\bigoplus` in display versus text styles, I offer here the use of a solution to dealing with `\bigoplus` in display style.

Here you can define a new math operator `\medoplus`, which uses the `\textstyle` version of `\bigoplus`, even in displayed equations.

EDITED to provide for smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*\medoplus{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle\bigoplus}
  {\textstyle\bigoplus}
  {\scriptstyle\bigoplus}
  {\scriptscriptstyle\bigoplus}
}
\begin{document}
This is inline with \verb|\limits| $\bigoplus\limits_1^2$ versus textstyle $\medoplus_1^2$.
\[\mbox{displaystyle} \bigoplus_1^2 \mbox{versus textstyle operator} \medoplus_1^2
\]
And now for other math styles
\[
\medoplus_1^2\quad \scriptstyle \medoplus_1^2 \quad \scriptscriptstyle \medoplus_1^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]